# How to integrate swagger into ASP.NET Core Web API with identity server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I have integrated Swagger into my ASP.NET Core Web API project, but it can only access endpoints that do not require authentication:

```
application.UseSwagger();
application.UseSwaggerUI();
```

How can I approach this? Is there a way to expose the Identity endpoints and input the user credentials there?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should request jwt token from identity server. Then for the api which protect by jwt "bearer" authentication scheme, You could configure swagger like following to add jwt token when access api.

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(option =>
{
    option.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Demo API", Version = "v1" });
    option.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter a valid token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id="Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[]{}
        }
    });
});
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I managed to do it this way. Any way to redirect to the login page and then back to swagger without having to manually input the token?